# Moving Embedded JS to Separate File

Tags: javascript

I want the embedded script in my page footer to be combined with other JS in a bundle.js file.

When I successfully add it to the file - the function below doesn't add the attributes to my external links as it before.

How do I adjust the code to make it work?

### Combined JS

Placed in the footer

```
<script src="{{ '/assets/js/bundle.js' | url }}"></script>
```

### Embedded Script

Placed in the footer - want to add to bundle.js

```
<script>
    (function () {
        const links = document.querySelectorAll("a[href^='https://'], a[href^='http://']")
        const host = window.location.hostname

        const isInternalLink = link => new URL(link).hostname === host
        links.forEach(link => {
            if (isInternalLink(link)) return

            link.setAttribute("target", "_blank")
            link.setAttribute("rel", "noopener")
            link.setAttribute("data-splitbee-event", "External Link")
            link.setAttribute("data-splitbee-event-type", link.hostname)
        })
    })()
</script>
```

### Bundle File

```
---
permalink: "/assets/js/bundle.js.njk"
---
{% set js %}
{% include "../assets/js/main.js" %}
{% include "../assets/js/search.js" %}

// place embedded scrip in external-links.js
{% include "../assets/js/external-links.js" %}
{% endset %}
{{ js | minifyJs | safe }}
```

Comment: What SSR/compiler are you using for `"{{ '/assets/js/bundle.js' | url }}"` to be your `<script>`'s `src`? And is the script at the bottom of the question a `.js` file that you're wanting to inject? If so, then you should have `<script> ... </script>` wrapped around it.

Comment: I'm using eleventy https://www.11ty.dev/docs/ - the embedded script is in the main layout file - (a nunjuks file) and placed just before the closing body tag.

Comment: so bundle.js.njk gets converted to bundle.js